# match arms: "mismatched types expected (), found integral variable"

Tags: rust

I wrote the following code to parse a string to get the integer encoded in it, and check for errors using `match`. If I get an `Err(e)` I want to print out the error `e`, and return a default value.

```
return match t.parse::<usize>() {
    Ok(n) => n,
    Err(e) => {
        println!("Couldn't parse the value for gateway_threads {}", e);
        // Return two as a default value
        return 2;
    },
};
```

However, that code fails to compile, as it expects type `()` but got an integer:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:37:32
   |
37 |                         return 2;
   |                                ^ expected (), found integral variable
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `{integer}
```

If I remove the return of a default value I get the error `` expected usize but got `()` ``:

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:33:24
   |
33 |                   return match t.parse::<usize>() {
   |  ________________________^
34 | |                     Ok(n) => n,
35 | |                     Err(e) => {
36 | |                         println!("Couldn't parse the value for gateway_threads {}", e); //TODO: Log this
37 | |                         //return 2;
38 | |                     },
39 | |                 };
   | |_________________^ expected usize, found ()
   |
   = note: expected type `usize`
              found type `()`
note: match arm with an incompatible type
  --> src/main.rs:35:31
   |
35 |                       Err(e) => {
   |  _______________________________^
36 | |                         println!("Couldn't parse the value for gateway_threads {}", e); //TODO: Log this
37 | |                         //return 2;
38 | |                     },
   | |_____________________^
```

Full code (I'm parsing an INI config file to get some of my values):

```
extern crate threadpool;
extern crate ini;

use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::io::Read;
use std::process;
use threadpool::ThreadPool;
use ini::Ini;

fn main() {

    let mut amount_workers: usize;
    let mut network_listen = String::with_capacity(21);
    //Load INI
    {
        let conf: Ini = match Ini::load_from_file("/etc/iotcloud/conf.ini") {
            Ok(t) => t,
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Error load ini file {}", e);
                process::exit(0);
            },
        };
        let section = match conf.section(Some("network".to_owned())) {
            Some(t) => t,
            None => {
                println!("Couldn't find the network ");
                process::exit(0);
            },
        };
        //amount_workers = section.get("gateway_threads").unwrap().parse().unwrap();
        amount_workers = match section.get("gateway_threads") {
            Some(t) => {
                return match t.parse::<usize>() {
                    Ok(n) => n,
                    Err(e) => {
                        println!("Couldn't parse the value for gateway_threads {}", e);
                        // Return two as a default value
                        return 2; //ERROR HERE;
                    },
                };
            },
            None => 2, // Return two as a default value
        };
        let ip = section.get("bind_ip").unwrap();
        let port = section.get("bind_port").unwrap();
        network_listen.push_str(ip);
        network_listen.push_str(":");
        network_listen.push_str(port);
    }
}
```

What causes this error?

Comment: What do you want to do in the `Err` branch? You have to return *something*, or call `panic!(…)`.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer I want o return 2  to set a default value. It's in a comment because I got the error expected (), found integral variable

Comment: But with `return 2`, it does compile, right? If not, please show the error for that, not error for the code variant you are not actually interested in.

Comment: Nope I'll get the first error you see on the top.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on because your example is incomplete. You need to show at least the complete function. It looks like it returns `()` and not `usize`.

Comment: Blind guess: @Olof is trying to "return" from the match.  If that's the case: you can't.  `return` returns from the function.  There is no way to "early exit" a match with a value.

Comment: I added now all the code in my project. Which is almost the same.

Comment: @DK then how is the intended way to do it if you want to set a default value when you get an error?

Comment: I somehow solved it.

Comment: @Olof Glad to hear! Would you consider accepting my answer if it helped you somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
amount_workers = match section.get("gateway_threads") {
    Some(t) => {
        return match t.parse::<usize>() {
            Ok(n) => n,
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Couldn't parse the value for gateway_threads {}", e); //TODO: Log this
                return 2; //ERROR HERE; //Default value is set to 2
            }
        };
    }
    None => 2, //Default value is set to 2
};
```

to

```
amount_workers = match section.get("gateway_threads") {
    Some(t) => {
        match t.parse::<usize>() {  // No return
            Ok(n) => n,
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Couldn't parse the value for gateway_threads {}", e); //TODO: Log this
                2  // No semicolon, no return
            }
        } // No semicolon
    }
    None => 2, //Default value is set to 2
};
```

Not ending a statement with `;` is how you return values in Rust. The `return` keyword is used when you want an entire function to return a value before the last line, which is why you call it an "early return".

You find more information about how Rust treats expressions [here](https://barafael.github.io/Statements-and-Expressions-in-Rust/).